# Share data extracted from one script with another script

Tags: python-3.x, process, communication

I'm trying to communicate 2 scripts with each other. For the purpose of this question, let's say I have a website with a table, and I have a script (script1) which reads from the table, and goes through every row getting a name. 
My other script (script2) points to a different website, and looks for a particular string to search it within the web.

What I want is once script1 has gotten a name, to communicate it with script2, which will look for it in its own website, and will return wether it was found or not.

I thought of using multiprocessing to launch both scripts at the same time, but I'm a bit lost on how to make them communicate. Which would be the best way to approach this issue?

Answer (score 0):

First things first, I haven't worked with multiprocessing before, so I might be overlooking some sort of solution there. Aside from that, three ideas, all of which will likely require some modification to your scripts.

1. **Combine the scripts.** Would it be possible to make them both functions in a single program? What if script2 was a function inside of script1 that returned a boolean? Keeping the scripts separate is a valid design choice that you could make, but it might make your life harder in the long run.
2. **Make script2 an importable module.** This would allow script1 to call script2's functions easily. [Here's a guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-write-modules-in-python-3#writing-and-importing-modules) on how to do that; in short, if script1.py and script2.py are in the same directory, `import script2` will work. Then you can call `script2.lookup(string_to_search)` or whatever you want.
3. **Use [`subprocess.run()`](https://pymotw.com/3/subprocess/#running-external-command).** This will let you run a shell command from inside python and get its output. It is the messiest of all the solutions I can think of, but worth including here because it may function in some cases where the other two options are not practical/don't work. You'll need to [make script2 take command line arguments for input](https://pythonprogramminglanguage.com/command-line-arguments/), and then parse the output string returned from `subprocess.run()`.

Comment: My issue here would be that if I do so, I would need for each time script2 is called, to initialize its browser (they use selenium as their websites are heavy on js) and that would slow down quite a bit my total time of execution. I guess I could save browser2 in a config file and try to have access to it each time. But, would that be faster/more robust than for example using sockets?

Comment: Oh. I see. Then running the second script multiple times would be prohibitive. Could you parse the table from the first webpage into a list, or something (the table is static, right, so you might be able to just `wget` it and search it as an offline file, or reformat it as a csv), and then keep the same browser2 window open and look up each entry in sequence? Also, I wonder if you could just manually send GET requests to the search from script2 and do away with the overhead of a full browser altogether? It would be really convenient if the replies were in a json format.